# stencil as shader resourceview

Tags: shaders, resource-management, stencil

I would like to use the stencil information in my depthstencil buffer as shaderresourceview (DX11) in my shader.
I have a DSV D24S8 from which I create a R24X8 resource fine using the red for shadowing but can't use the X8 of course
So I try to create a parallel resource X24G8. DX says no error but I'm not sure this is allowed or can work as what I get is a black square when i visualize the stencil X24G8 resource on the screen using the green chanel.
Or maybe I'm not reading this correctly. I just send the green value to the pixel shader or try other multiplication stuff to modifty the value but nothing changes.

Is it even possible to create a resource from stencil or a texture declaration in shader can be used to reinterpret the data from R24X8?

thanks

Comment: How do your shaders work?

Comment: can you be more presice on that question. I'm currently using the depth stencil red channel for shadows. As I'm doing stencil mirror I would like to use the stencil data too for some specific calculation for mirrors.

Comment: if you're talking about the shader for the stencil it is at the moment only a simple shader just to see the texture content on the screen: color = txdiffuse.sample(sampoint, input.tex).g. with txdiffuse being the depth buffer content used as its shaderresourceview in format X24typeless_G8_uint.

Comment: What type is `txdiffuse`?

Comment: Texture2D txDiffuse : register(t0); may I set a specific format like <float2>

Comment: Finally in debug mode it says x24_G8 format did not support sample, sample/level/bias/grad. I'm not aware of other texture.methods. I'll take a look at.

Comment: Your stencil texture is uint. it needs to be uint2

Comment: Well cant get it work. "Texture2D <uint2>txStencil : register(t6);\n", in pixshader trying to use load becasue X24G8 does not support sampleXXX funcs: int2 uColor = txStencil.Load(int3(500, 500,0)); error msg: The resource return type for component 0 declared in the shader code (FLOAT) is not compatible with the Shader Resource View format bound to slot 0 of the Pixel Shader unit (UINT).  This mismatch is invalid if the shader actually uses the view (e.g. it is not skipped due to shader code branching). [ EXECUTION ERROR #361: DEVICE_DRAW_RESOURCE_RETURN_TYPE_MISMATCH]

Comment: show the code where you create the texture and the views of it.

Comment: D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC TD;TD.Width=W;TD.Height=H;TD.MipLevels=1;TD.ArraySize=1; TD.Format=DXGI_FORMAT_R24G8_TYPELESS; TD.SampleDesc.Count=1;TD.SampleDesc.Quality=0;TD.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;TD.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;TD.CPUAccessFlags = 0;TD.MiscFlags = 0; gpD11->CreateTexture2D(&TD, NULL, &pTex);
D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC SD;SD.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_X24_TYPELESS_G8_UINT; SD.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D; SD.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;SD.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0; gpD11->CreateShaderResourceView(pText2D, &SD, &pSRV);

Comment: ok get it working now. a silly mistake in my shader constant buffer